Struggling to understand the reasoning behind the "D operator" method in solving linear ODEs.
In my ODE course at school, we were introduced to various techniques for solving differential equations, but without any proofs or explanations—just formulas and methods to memorize. I’m struggling to understand the reasoning behind one technique in particular: the "D operator" method.
Here’s what I know about this method:
Suppose we have a linear differential equation with constant coefficients, in the form
the form $y''+ay' +b=P(x)$ (it could be of any order really ) where P(x) is a polynomial (also works for other functions). The D operator method involves rewriting the equation as follows:
$$y = \frac{P(x)}{D^2 + aD + b}$$
then to find the particular solution we set $y =\frac{P(x)}{D^2+aD+b}$ then expand $\frac{1}{D^2+aD+b}$ as a series and then differentiate. For example $1-y''= x^6 $ we have that $y =\frac{x^6 }{1-D^2}=(x^6 )(1+D^2 +D^4+D^6+D^8+....) =x^6+30x^4+360x^2+720$
My concern is how to rigorously prove all of these steps or how to justify it.

What exactly is an operator? How does it work in the context of differential equations? How to rigorously define it?
How can we justify expanding $\frac{1}{1_D}$ as a geometric series, I know how to prove that it converges for $|z|<1 , z\in \mathbb{C}$ and why it works for complex but why does it work with $D$?
How is the fraction $\frac{1}{1-D}$ defined with an operator like $D$? In particular, what does this fraction mean, and how do we interpret expressions like $D^2$ (I know it is the second derivative but how did the expansion in the geometric series turns the nth power to the nth derivative?  )
How does multiplying the series by the function lead to derivatives?
Is there a field or course that studies these concepts rigorously? I’ve studied real analysis mainly form Rudin's books and haven’t found any mention of this operator approach or how to justify or prove any of these steps. Would functional analysis cover this, or is there another area of mathematics that treats operators in this way?


It seems to me like this can be analysed using (finite dimensional) linear algebra, choosing as a vector space $V$ the space of polynomials of degree $\leq$ the degree of $P$ and then computing the inverse of $D^2 + a D +b$ (as a linear map without the bogus fraction) which will lead to a similar "geometric series" expansion. Here the derivative is simply a linear map $D: V\to V$.

(mostly links to things of possible help, not really an answer to your questions) Possibly useful are Geometric series of an operator and maybe this MSE answer. However, if you're learning basic methods for solving ordinary differential equations, then I recommend for now just focusing on learning the "algebraic manipulative aspects" for applying the method, and deal with the theoretical issues later (continued)

(later introductory applied treatment -- Operational Mathematics by Ruel V. Churchill; later introductory pure treatment -- Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications by Erwin Kreyszig). For now the discussions of operators in Ordinary Differential Equations by Gabriel Nagy seems especially nice -- search this .pdf document for "operator" to find these discussions of operators.

Earlier I intended to mention this MSE answser, but forgot after looking up the other stuff I mentioned.


$(1-D)\sum_{k=0}^n D^k=1-D^{n+1}$ If $D^{n+1}\rightarrow 0$, you find $(1-D)\sum_{k=0}^\infty D^k=1$, i.e. $\frac{1}{1-D}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty D^k$


@user408858: I suspect the OP knows how to obtain, and prove convergence of, geometric series. I believe the actual concern here (or one of them, to be more accurate) is what does $D^{n+1}\rightarrow 0$ mean when $D$ is the operation of taking the derivative of a function. (moments later) However, in looking more carefully at the questions, I guess the first part of #2 appears to say that obtaining and proving geometric series expansions is one of the concerns. If that's one of the concerns, then I think it's way too early for the OP to be worrying about ODEs.

@DaveL.Renfro To rephrase 2 more clearly: How can we justify turning $\frac{1}{1-D}$ as a geometric series, I know how to prove that it converges for $|z|<1 , z\in \mathbb{C}$ but why does it work with $D$?

@DaveL.Renfro My guess is, it takes it to zero. Depends on the function space you are looking at, but if you differentiate often enough, you find the derivative to be equal to zero? This is how I would have interpreted $\sum_{k=0}^\infty D^k$ or $D^{n+1}$ for very large $n$'s intuitively.

The 'operator' $D$ is a function that acts on functions. Specifically, we have $D(f) = f'$ whenever $f$ is differentiable. It's also possible to interpret a scalar like $2$ as an operator -- a function that acts on functions -- where $2:f \mapsto 2f$.
We can do arithmetic with functions. You might remember in algebra calculating things like $(f+g)(x)$ or $(fg)(x)$ given two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Since $D$ is a function, you can do things like this with it too. So for instance we can consider a new operator $D+2$, which does the following to a function $f$:
$$(D+2)(f) = D(f) + 2(f) = f'+2f $$
Writing $D^2$ means applying $D$ twice, so $D^2(f) = D(f')=f''$ and so on for higher powers.
Operator notation for a DE is a way to think of the left-hand-side of the DE itself as an operator that acts on the solution to the DE. For example
$$y-y'' = (1-D^2)y$$
The benefit of this approach is exactly that you can now do algebra with this "LHS operator", like you have learned to do in your examples. Getting into the details of proving that it works is beyond the scope of this answer I think, but some good relevant other questions are linked in the comments.

$$\text{Wrong}:\require{enclose}\enclose{updiagonalstrike,downdiagonalstrike}{y = \frac{P(x)}{D^2 + aD + b}}$$
$$\text{Correct}: y= \frac{1}{D^2 + aD + b}P(x),\,\text{or better:}\,\, y=(D^2+aD+b)^{-1}P(x)  $$
If $h(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ then $h(D)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n D^n$.
Example 1: Find the particular solution of the ODE, $(D+a)y=x^2.$
Solution: Since $(x+a)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^n}{a^{n+1}}$, the particular solution is $y=(D+a)^{-1}x^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nD^nx^2}{a^{n+1}}=\frac{x^2}a-\frac {2x}{a^2}+\frac2{a^3}.$
Example 2: Find the particular solution of the ODE, $(D^2+(a+b)D+ab)y=x^2.$
Solution: By using example 1, $y=(D+b)^{-1}(D+a)^{-1}x^2=(D+b)^{-1}(\frac{x^2}a-\frac {2x}{a^2}+\frac2{a^3})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nD^n}{b^{n+1}}(\frac{x^2}a-\frac {2x}{a^2}+\frac2{a^3})\\=\frac{x^2}{ab}-\frac{2x}{ab^2}+\frac2{ab^3}-\frac{2x}{a^2b}+\frac{2}{a^2b^2}+\frac2{a^3b}=\frac{x^2}{ab}-\frac{2(a+b)x}{a^2b^2}+\frac{2(a^2+ab+b^2)}{a^3b^3}.$
More examples can be given. Note that "D" is the differentiation operator defined by $Dy=y'$.

How can you put $D$ in the place of $x$? the geometric series converge absolutely when $|z|<1$ and this justifies the expansion but how do you justify it for $D$? D is not a complex number so you can't just plug it into the formula

@pie Yes, I need to give justification or reference, I know. This is a tricky method that I remember from late 80s, early 90s. Have you seen this method before? Is my answer that bad? How can I improve it?

It is not that bad, you can improve it by adding justifications or/and reference that explain this in more details, no I haven't seen this before

The simplest approach is the best:  With differential equations, it's It's always hard to prove that a particular method will yield a solution.  But, once you have a candidate for solution, it's always  easy to prove that a particular function $y(x)$ is (or is not) - just differentiate.  So don't try to prove that a method will work.  Just use, and prove that it did work.
Think this is amateurish? It's not. It's used by the greatest mathematicians.
So, instead of proving that the $D$ operator will produce meaningful results, just use it, and prove the candidate you get is correct (which is as easy as taking a deriviative).
